# redirect old url to new url in htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

my website have old url and it not friendly for SEO , so i need to redirect all my old to new url . but it not working. can anyone can help me or give me solution . Thanks

orl url :

```
/country?cn=United%20Arab%20Emirates&s-country=312
/country?cn=Dominican%20Republic&s-country=534
/country?cn=United%20Kingdom&s-country=268
```

new url:

```
/country/united-arab-emirates-city-tours
/country/dominican-republic-city-tours
/country/united-kingdom-city-tours
```

my htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^country?cn=([a-zA-Z_-]+)&s-country=([0-9]+)$           index.php?cmd=country&countryname=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^country/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)-city-tours$           index.php?cmd=country&countryname=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: You can not use RewriteRule to match the query string, it checks against the path component of the URL only. To do any matching on the query string, you need a RewriteCond.

Comment: And you really don't need the numeric "s-country" attribute to process those requests? Since that argument is not present in the "clean URL" examples and cannot somehow be _guessed_ by the http server...

Answer (score 0):

Hi @Asamoa I share some of my experience here:

I am using **Wordpress** and database **cpanel** while dealing with changing url. You may access to **cpanel**(or **phpmyadmin**) to change your url from backend there. It will redirect to the new url.

Since I am using **Wordpress**, I installed **Yoast SEO**, you may try reading some of the useful blogging that provided from them, see [here](https://yoast.com/6-questions-about-redirects-for-seo/).

I hope it helps!